# how can I get the selected row data from Jtable through another classs extended by JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans

I have here class [StudentPatientForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJSC4.png) and [MedicineForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvugh.png) extended with  JFrame. Please take note that the StudentPatientForm class here is the first one to call and the MedicineForm called here by the Medical Data button action event  from StudentPatientForm. Now in MedicineForm I have method called showTableData() and the code is like this

```
public void showTableData() {
 
try{
     String query = "SELECT `Medicine_Id`, `Date_Added`, `Medicine_Name`, `Quantity` FROM 
     patient_medicine WHERE `Stud_Patient_Id` = '"++"'";
    //supposedly this query is to retrieve the data from a database 
    //where the foreign key(Stud_Patient_Id) is equal to the selected
    // row value Id from Jtable(StudentPatientForm)
     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_medical_system? 
     zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
     pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
     rs = pst.executeQuery();

     while (rs.next()) {
         String medicineId = rs.getString("Medicine_Id");
         Date dateAdded = rs.getDate("Date_Added");
         String medicineName = rs.getString("Medicine_Name");
         String quantity = rs.getString("Quantity");

         Object[] obj = {medicineId, dateFormatForJTable.format(dateAdded), medicineName, 
         quantity};
         model = (DefaultTableModel) tblMedicine.getModel();
         model.addRow(obj);
    }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

And this method showTableData() is being called to MedicineForm Constructor. Can someone tell me how can I Achieve that? Any suggestion would help

Comment: Pass the StudentPatientID to the class as a parameter when you create an instance of the form.

Comment: can u give me an example

Comment: An example of what? Do you not know how to pass parameters? It would be something like: `MedicineForm mf = new MedicineForm(studentPatientId)`. So in the action listener of your button you first get the selected row of the JTable. Then use use the `getValueAt(...)` method of the JTable to get the student id.

Comment: No, that's not how this work and what Camickr is suggesting is basic programming 101, if you don't understand what he's describing, you have bigger problems and really shouldn't be getting involved GUI development